# UFW: Allow traffic only from a dynamic IP on its last 2 elements

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ufw

I am trying to setup the following rule on ufw:

```
ufw allow from 217.87.123.0/24
```

So to allow incoming connections from all 217.87.123.* addresses.

The problem is that my IP does not always start with 217.87.123.*, it changed today to 217.87.115.*

Any ideas on how to setup ufw for this to work?
I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I figured a short workaround which is not entirely perfect:

I set the rule to accept IP's in the range:

217.87.0.0/16

This means only the first 16 bytes of the IP are static and the rest dynamic.
I guess it's more secure than not adding any rule at all.